# Change location of panes when mobile

Tags: dotnetnuke

In desktop view we have a left pane and a side pane. The left pane has a great deal of content, so much so that when rendered on a mobile device the side pane is missed by users.

When rendered on a mobile device the left pane is rendered first and then the side pane is rendered after the left pane. Is there a way to change this behavior so that the side pane is rendered above the left pane when in a mobile browser?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap, foundation, or some other framework for your responsive design?

Comment: DNN8 is now using Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

To place one pane over the other on certain screen sizes, we use z-index.

To do this, simply change your pane z-index using css:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
   .leftpane{
      z-index: 2;
   }
   .sidepane{
      z-index: 3;
   }
}
```

Let me know if this works for you. Thanks!

Comment: Finally got this to run, I did have to change the assigning of the CSS to  $('.leftPane').attr('style', 'display: block !important');  Yet when it ran it just put the leftPane in the exact same spot.

Comment: Hmm. I may have misunderstood your question. Are you wanting one pane above the other? In this case, you can use the "z-index" property in css. Then, you can load the z-index as different values depending on the screen size.

Comment: I have changed the answer to what I think you are looking for. This places your side pane above your left pane on mobile devices. Your left pane must have a class 'leftpane' and your side pane must have a class 'sidepane'.

Comment: Z-Index would be layered on top. What we were trying to accomplish on the mobile device was from visually top to bottom for the user to see the sidepane and then scroll farther down before they see the left pane. The reason being is that the left pane has a great deal of content. So wanted to save that for the last item viewed on the page. We ended up accomplishing this by having a separate mobile page and using DNN capability to redirect based on device.

Answer (score 0):

The first element found in the skin will be the first one rendered. There is no way to change that (as far as I know).
But it could be as easy as switching two div elements in the DNN skin page.

```
<div id="SidePane" class="SidePane" runat="server">
<div id="LeftPane" class="LeftPane" runat="server">
```

instead of

```
<div id="LeftPane" class="LeftPane" runat="server">
<div id="SidePane" class="SidePane" runat="server">
```

But depending on the CSS and the HTML design of the skin this could be an easy fix or completely destroy the site design. If you bought the skin at the [DNN store](http://store.dnnsoftware.com/) (or another vendor) it could be worth trying to ask the seller.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up accomplishing our goal by having a separate page for mobile with a different layout. DNN then has a capability to redirect to a different page if mobile device detected.